# Python seaborn facetgrid x-axis dates not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can we plot a facetgrid with datetime values as shown in the first example below.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import seaboarn as sns

test = [{"date": date.today(), "categ": "test1", "value": 100}, {"date": date.today() - timedelta(days=1), "categ": "test2", "value": 200}]

df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

**First Example using seaborn**

```
ax= sns.barplot("date","value", data=df)
```

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqmJC.png)

**Second Example using FacetGrid**

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='categ')
g.map(plt.bar, "date", "value")
```

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLAhg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your second part:

**FROM:**

```
g.map(plt.bar, "date", "value")
```

**TO:**

```
g.map(sns.barplot, "date", "value")
```